# Converting XSLT 1.0 to XSLT 2.0

Tags: php, xml, qt, xslt

I'm using XSLT 1.0 an want to transform an XML file. It works fine with *IE 6.0* and *Firefox 3.0.11*. However, the *PHP 5.2.6 XSLTProcessor* (providing XSLT 1.0) and *Qt C++ QXmlQuery* (providing only XSLT 2.0) generates blank output.

I think of two options:

1. Convert it to XSLT 2.0 (preferred)
2. Extract Firefox part to parse.

The *W3C* specs seem to long for me to digest and the documents to transform are not that large.

Comment: You edited your title into "... [closed]" instead of actually *closing* the question?! That's not how it is supposed to work. Look for the "close" link if you must close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT should be pretty much backward compatibly, although obviously there are things you can use in XSLT 2.0 that make life much easier.

It sounds like you have something wrong in your XSLT, but as you don't provide anything for us to look at it is hard to say.

I would recommend getting hold of Kernow-for-Saxon - it is a great UI for testing XSLT (much better than trying to use Firefox or IE) and if you have errors in your XSLT then Saxon is one of the better XSLT processors for giving good errors to try to identify the cause.

http://kernowforsaxon.sourceforge.net/

I don't know anything about either the PHP or Qt processors, but it is possible there are errors in them that are not handling your XSLT correctly.

Comment: Hi samjudson, I will upload later today both XML and XSLT files so that you could check. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the whole spec is too long (???), start with the [Changes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#changes) section.

Also, XSLTProcessor  is just a wrapper round libxslt, and unlikely to break on a valid XSLT 1.0 transform. I wonder if there is something funky about your transformation that you can fix without going to 2.0, or if there's something wrong with your XSLTProcessor deployment. Can you successfully apply other transformations?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I use XPath in matching tags. I tried with IE and Firefox, they worked but none work with other tools as I mentioned. I'm trying the W3School tool to adjust. So far it doesn't work.

Comment: @Viet: My guess is also that you are doing something wrong. Apart from the fact that XSLT 2.0 processors execute 1.0 code just fine, I think your time is better spent finding the error, instead of reading XSLT 2.0 spec.

Comment: I found that the Tidy converted HTML not into strict XML so XSLT parpsers I listed don't give output. I use Mozilla nsIXSLTProcessor instead. The HTML input is not controlled by me so I can do nothing with it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Viet: there is an option in tidy that *will* make it output well-formed XML.

Comment: Which one? I need strictly well-formed XML. Thank you.

Comment: Here u go:

Processing directives
---------------------
...
 -xml                specify the input is well formed XML
 -asxml, -asxhtml    convert HTML to well formed XHTML
 -ashtml             force XHTML to well formed HTML
 -access <level>     do additional accessibility checks (<level> = 0, 1, 2, 3).
                     0 is assumed if <level> is missing.

No option to produce strictly well-formed XML.

Comment: @Tomalak: So silent? Please tell me how to use XML to give well-formed XML output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much of hardwork and painful testing, I found the answer myself:

1. A valid XSLT 1.0 file is also a valid XSLT 1.0 file
2. PHP and Qt C++ failed as I had `<html xslmn="...">` instead of just `<html>` (which IE & FF were able to transform successfully). For simplicity, I removed `<!DOCTYPE` and `<attributes` of the `<html>` tag.

Thanks everyone for participating in the discussion.